# Excel lookup in kettle 7

Tags: excel, lookup, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am new to kettle.. I need to use excel sheet lookup for my kettle job.
The problem is **stream** **lookup** which compares my excel sheet with the input rows requires exact match. Is there any other step that i can use instead of this
Fir example,

**Input** **row**: 196 harrington ave las Vegas

My excel lookup has a rows of address abbreviation. One such is 'ave'

In this case i need to check if my input row has any substring in the lookup.

Kindly suggest me the proper step.

By the way my input is **text** **file** **input** of multiple rows and lookup input is **excel** **sheet**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Regex evaluation' step and use an expression like `^.*ave.*$` and replacing 'ave' with whatever substring you want to search for. You can then use something like 'Filter rows' to filter out rows that don't match your criteria.